# Improve readability of barplot

Tags: r

This is my data:

```
dput(DATA)
structure(c(-0.01728, 0.00072, -0.02452, -0.02589, -0.00376, 
            -0.05394, -0.07508, -0.00671, -0.10151, -0.05788, -0.09119, -0.07414, 
            -0.08645, -0.00465, -0.04487, -0.02463, -0.06887, -0.0426, -0.03045, 
            -0.00063, -0.00097, -0.04478, 0.00311, 40.112684060182, 962.704417444368, 
            28.2686452104382, 26.7727763831574, 184.347654404241, 12.8503370515377, 
            9.23211481832639, 103.300623034269, 6.8283635165003, 11.9755905418097, 
            7.60113148985574, 9.34916617965937, 8.0178968254476, 149.063909797838, 
            15.4478979398249, 28.1423946634164, 10.0645735524894, 16.2710605765245, 
            22.7634542055811, 1100.23361993642, 714.584722226748, 15.4789455238934, 
            222.876906932458, 43.2, 1.8, 61.3, 64.725, 9.4, 134.85, 187.7, 
            16.775, 253.775, 144.7, 227.975, 185.35, 216.125, 11.625, 112.175, 
            61.575, 172.175, 106.5, 76.125, 1.575, 2.425, 111.95, 7.775), .Dim = c(23L, 
                                                                                   3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
                                                                                                           "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
                                                                                                           "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
                                                                                                           "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
                                                                                                           "23"), c("SAD", "T", "CC")))
```

This is a a code I use for plotting:

```
xx <- barplot(abs(DATA[, "CC"]), ylab="CC", ylim=c(0,20+max(abs(DATA[, "CC"]))),las=2, space = 1, width = 2, cex.names = 0.75, cex.axis = 0.5, cex=0.5)
    text(x = xx, y = signif(abs(DATA[, "CC"]), digits=2), label = signif(abs(DATA[, "CC"]), digits=2), pos = 3, cex = 0.75, col = "black")
```

And that's how the plot looks like:

[image: Example]

So I use this code for plotting my data. The problem is that number of bars is usually different. Sometimes it might be just 5 of bars and other day more then 30.

Is there any way to make this barplot more readable ?
Is there a way to make a look of graph dependent on number of variables to plot. Just to be sure that every time it will be readable?

Comment: Suggestions: (1) rotate the numbers too, to prevent overlap. (2) Optionally switch to `ggplot2`, and use the `ggrepel` package to ensure no text labels overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Updated*** See below

I like @IanCambell 's idea of rotating the graph. +1.  You can get that from the base R plot that you had with only minor changes.

```
xx <- barplot(abs(DATA[, "CC"]), ylab="CC", xlim=c(0,20+max(abs(DATA[, "CC"]))),
    las=2, space = 1, width = 2, cex.names = 0.75, cex.axis = 0.5, cex=0.5, horiz=T)
text(y = xx, x = signif(abs(DATA[, "CC"]), digits=2), 
label = signif(abs(DATA[, "CC"]), digits=2), pos = 4, cex = 0.75, col = "black")
```

[image: Horizontal Barplot]

**Update** Based on comment from OP

If the labels to be displayed are too long, then you need to adjust so that they can be displayed. For example, changing the labels on the original question and just plugging into the above code gives a bad result.

[image: Bargraph With Truncated Labels]

Of course you *could* fix this by just increasing the xlim, but that would also include some additional unwanted values on the x-axis. So a different solution is to allow the text to go outside the plot region (add `xpd=NA` to the `text` statement) and increase the margin to allow enough room for the labels.

```
par(mar=c(5,4,4,10))
xx <- barplot(abs(DATA[, "CC"]), ylab="CC", xlim=c(0,20+max(abs(DATA[, "CC"]))),
     las=2, space = 1, width = 2, cex.names = 0.75, cex.axis = 0.5, cex=0.5, horiz=T)
text(y = xx, x = signif(abs(DATA[, "CC"]), digits=3), xpd=NA,
    label = labels, pos = 4, cex = 0.75, col = "black")
```

[image: Bargraph displaying full labels]

Comment: That looks good but in purpose I avoided rotating a graph because names of bars can be quite long and in this case there is not enough space. I just changed a real names to random numbers. Is there any way to give a bit more space for labels ?

Comment: Yes, adding to answer.

Answer (score 3):

A solution involving `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` turned out to be quite challenging. Perhaps this will help anyway:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = as.data.frame(DATA), aes(x = as.factor(seq_along(CC)),  y = CC)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(label = signif(CC,2)), hjust = -0.2) +
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.05))) +
  theme_classic() + theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]